# how to schedule a salesforce job every 3 months?

Tags: scheduled-apex, schedulebatch, scheduled-job

Someone know how to cron a salesforce job every 3 months, on the 1st at 9am?
any ideas?

Comment: Unfortunately, we cannot use /3 or something like that, so I'm afraid you'll to schedule your job 4 times. Or you could schedule it on the first of each month, and change the code so that it just returns in the months it should not run.

Comment: how can I schedule on the 1st of x month?

Comment: By using the cron expression `0 0 9 1 x ? *`. The first three digits are the time, so 0 seconds, 0 minutes, 9 hours, the last four are for the day, so first of the month, x-th month, no specifier for day of the week and every year. Also check the documentation for Apex Schedules: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_scheduler.htm

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: Right, turns out I was wrong, you can use 1/3 to schedule every third month. See Mahmood's answer.

Answer (score 2):

You will need to schedule using cron expression, something like

```
apexScheduledJob j = new apexScheduledJob ();
String sch = '0 0 9 1 1/3 ? *';
System.schedule('My Job', sch, j);
```

Use [cronmaker](http://www.cronmaker.com/) to generate crons for any requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Cross posting for duplicate question on Salesforce Stackexchange.

[Salesforce: how to schedule a task to run on the first day of every quarter](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/81509/salesforce-how-to-schedule-a-task-to-run-on-the-first-day-of-every-quarter/81599#81599)

you can check this link for reference. and please before posting something here you can surf something then you can get those available solutions.

Comment: You are right, this is a duplicate. Can you please remove your anwer and put it in the comments section of the question?

Comment: i can not able do that anyway, your answer helped him Good.

Comment: Actually I was referring to your answer, so if you remove your answer and put it as a comment , it would make more sense.